# Setting up SAS hotkey to refresh file

Tags: sas

I am using Sublime text editor to do the majority of my code writing in SAS.  The only real issue is that I have to run the file in batch mode and cannot run individual bits of code easily.  For the most part this does not bother me but occasionally it is nice to have SAS and Sublime open at the same time working on the same file.  If I change something in SAS and save it sublime automatically refreshes the file and changes.  Unfortunately, SAS does not return the favor.  I have been messing around with using the autoexec.sas file and the display manager but I am having issues. This bit of code will close the file and open it again.

```
dm editor 'winclose' editor; dm editor 'inc "%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)"' editor;
```

I then tried to put this in a macro

```
%macro Refresh;
dm editor 'winclose' editor; 
dm 'inc "%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)"';
%mend;
```

and add the key definition

```
dm "keydef F12 '%NRSTR(%Refresh);";
```

When I hit F12 I get

```
ERROR: Two or more Commands Start with 'dm'. Please reenter.
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: For some reason, my session does not allow me to rebind keys, so i cannot fully test, but 2 things: (1) just executing your %refresh macro by writing it in the code, works over here. (2) can't you bind it directly to the key by pressing F9 and then entering %refresh there yourself for the F12 key? (not posting as answer since i cannot verify )

Comment: A possible work around? With .sas-file open both in SAS and sublime (or Vim): edit file in sublime, save in sublime, close file in SAS without saving, open recent file in SAS. This loads newest files with the edits made in sublime. With shortcut set up, this might be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get that to work properly on my machine (the inc "...SAS_EXECFILEPATH..." does not work) but you definitely can remove the DM statements.  Keys is intelligent, it will figure what context you are in; so for example, in KEYS, in F12 I type:

```
F12: winclose editor;
```

and it closes the editor window.  Presumably you can use

```
F12: winclose editor; inc "something that works";
```

and that will work fine without all the DMs; or

```
F12: %refresh;
```

should also work.

Comment: That inc part of the function has issues unless you specify the path of the file you are working with.  Unfortunately, that is not flexible enough for general use.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a bit cleaner, but it works.  There are two parts:

1 - Compile the code below

2 - Run the following line: `%refresh();`, *in the program that needs to be refreshed* (to pick up SAS_EXEC_FILEPATH).  The line can then be deleted.

```
%macro Refresh(param=0);
%global file;
%if &param. =0 %then %do;
   %let file=%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH);
   %put file (&file) saved successfully.;
%end;
%else %do;
   %put file being loaded =&file;
   wpgm;clear;wpgm; inc "&file";
%end;
%mend;

dm "keydef F12 '%NRSTR(%Refresh(param=1));'";

/* 
1 - compile this macro
2 - run this code IN THE PROGRAM THAT NEEDS TO BE REFRESHED 
    %refresh()
3 - press F12 to refresh, whether program is open or closed..
*/
```

Comment: This works.  I like it but I wish I didn't have to put %refresh in all of my programs and it seems like if my work is not saved and I bump the hotkey that my work will be lost.  This is great though it is fulfilling my need.

Comment: Unfortunately, SAS does not detect underlying file changes, and 'refresh' automatically..  And even if it did, presumably there'd then also be a need for some kind of DIFF tool to manage the changes in both files!  Maybe instead, you would be better just working exclusively in one editor (eg Sublime) and using a %include "C:\myfile.sas"; statement to execute the code directly..